# Can't see or access my ubuntu VM shares from my windows 10 host

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, samba

Following on from my previous question: [Can I share a folder from ubuntu VM to windows host](https://superuser.com/questions/1550149/can-i-share-a-folder-from-ubuntu-vm-to-windows-host?noredirect=1#comment2357105_1550149)

I want to share a folder on my virtualbox ubuntu 18.04, so that my windows 10 can read/write to one of my working directories.

Nothing I am trying seems to be working very well. I have been reading: [Using Samba to share a folder from a Linux guest with a Windows host in VirtualBox](https://superuser.com/questions/258026/using-samba-to-share-a-folder-from-a-linux-guest-with-a-windows-host-in-virtualb) + links on from there and also this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-shared-folder-host-os-guest-os-virtual-box/

What I have done so far:

In ubuntu (guest):
 - sudo apt-get install samba
 - sudo vim /etc/samba/smb.conf 
    - wins support = yes
    - interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 192.168.250.250/24
    - usershare allow guests = yes
 - sudo ufw disable (disable firewall)
 - Right click /home/user/development (in the file manager) -> local network share:
    - tick Share this folder
    - tick both boxes (allow create/delete + guest access)
    - note I can see the green / red <--  --> share icon on this folder

On ubuntu virtualbox settings:
 - NAT network adapter (for internet access)
    - 10.0.2.15 inside the Ubuntu guest
    - 192.168.71.1 on windows host
 - Host-only adapter (for folder sharing only)
    - 192.168.250.250 inside the Ubuntu guest
    - 192.168.56.103 on windows host

On windows:
 - no actions take here yet, but windows IP address is: 192.168.1.108

Here is what I can/can't do from the windows host:

- Can **not** ping 10.0.2.15 - timeout
- Can ping 192.168.71.1
- Can **not** ping 192.168.250.250 - timeout
- Can ping 192.168.56.103
- In windows explorer: `\\10.0.2.15` - cannot access check spelling etc...
- In windows explorer: `\\192.168.71.1` - takes me to my windows shared folders
- In windows explorer: `\\192.168.250.250` - cannot access check spelling etc...
- In windows explorer: `\\192.168.56.103` - takes me to my windows shared folders
- In windows explorer: `\\10.0.2.15\development` - cannot access check spelling etc...
- In windows explorer: `\\192.168.71.1\development` - cannot access check spelling etc...
- In windows explorer: `\\192.168.250.250\development` - cannot access check spelling etc...
- In windows explorer: `\\192.168.56.103\development` - cannot access check spelling etc...

Here is what I can do on the Ubuntu VM:

- Can ping windows box ip address: 192.168.1.108
- Can access the internet
- I can acceess `smb://homegroup/` -> `smb://user-virtualbox/` and see my development folder.

Now I am not sure what to do or how to progress from here.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out that one of the methods of setting up a samba share (I can't find the link now) was telling my to setup a static IP address inside the VM for my host-only connection.

I just read another article that suggested that I use DHCP. I reset the connection to DHCP and then I was able to ping my host-only ethernet adapter from windows to my VM. Then after a little bit of tweaking I was able to setup the samba share.

I don't really understand why that did not work (with the static IP address), but just happy that DHCP fixed it!